# How to pass array "by reference" in C?

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference

This is what I'm trying to do but my code is either not compiling or giving me an unexpected output "BC" instead of just "B".

```
#include <stdio.h>

void removeFirstAndLastChar(char** string) {
    *string += 1; // Removes the first character
    int i = 0;
    for (; *string[i] != '\0'; i++);
    *string[i - 1] = '\0';
}

int main(void) {
    char* title = "ABC";
    removeFirstAndLastChar(&title);
    printf("%s", title);
    // Expected output: B
    return 0;
}
```

I looked through a lot of answers here related to passing pointers by reference but none of them seemed to contain the operations that I want to do in my removeFirstAndLastChar() function.

Comment: Undefined behavior for attempting to modify a string literal.

Comment: You should change `char* title = "ABC";` to `char title[] = "ABC";`

Comment: You need `(*string)[i]` instead of `*string[i]`.

Comment: @mch, both is correct and just a matter of taste...

Comment: @mch I don't want to do that because this example is taken from bigger code where I want it to be a pointer

Comment: @hb20007 Then dynamically allocate memory for the string using `malloc`.

Comment: The best thing you can do is read a book of C. SO is not a tutorial site. There are hundred of questions about that.

Comment: @Nidhoegger using a pointer to the literal is not correct at all, since the function modifies it.

Comment: @KerrekSB I tried that but I still get the incorrect output BC

Comment: "_my code is either not compiling or giving me an unexpected output_" - Err, What?

Comment: Sure, your code is still broken, but as far as effecting reference semantics in C that seemed like the biggest issue, at least for other readers.

Comment: [try this](http://ideone.com/iUEkCe)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY You don't even need a compound literal. You could just do `char storage[] = "ABC"; char *title = storage;`.

Comment: @CoolGuy Depends on the compiler

Comment: @melpomene: That would require a variable with no other use than having its address taken. The compound literal seems like an elegant way to achieve the same thing.

Comment: C does not support pass-by-reference. It is **strictly** pass-by-value.

Comment: ```char* title = "ABC";
```

Modifying a literal string in C is an undefined behavior. It can lead to the result you want as much as it can lead to a segfault. A good compiler will notify it to you with a warning like `error: assignment of read-only location 'name'`.

You can prevent it in C by using `const char * ` for literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not judge your algorithm or C conventions, friends who comment on your problem are totally right. But if you still do it in this way you can use this approach.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void removeFirstAndLastChar(char* string) {
    memmove(string,string+1,strlen(string));
    string[strlen(string)-1]=0;
}

int main(void) {
    char title[] = "ABC";
    removeFirstAndLastChar(title);
    printf("%s", title);
    // Expected output: B
    return 0;
}
```